# Gemset error when updating to Ruby 2.4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rvm, gemset

I'm updating from Ruby 2.0 to 2.4.2 using RVM, and receive the following error messages during an install using `$ rvm install ruby-2.4.2`:

```
Making gemset ruby-2.4.2 pristine - please wait

'command gem pristine --extensions bigdecimal --version 1.3.0 gem-wrappers --version 1.3.2 io-console --version 0.4.6 json --version 2.0.4 openssl --version 2.0.5 psych --version 2.2.2' failed, you need to fix this gems manually.
Error running '__rvm_with ruby-2.4.2 gemset_pristine',
please read /Users/myname/.rvm/log/1507820191_ruby-2.4.2/gemset.pristine-ruby-2.4.2.log

Making gemset ruby-2.4.2@global pristine - please wait

'command gem pristine --extensions bigdecimal --version 1.3.0 io-console --version 0.4.6 json --version 2.0.4 openssl --version 2.0.5 psych --version 2.2.2' failed, you need to fix this gems manually.
Error running '__rvm_with ruby-2.4.2@global gemset_pristine',
please read /Users/myname/.rvm/log/1507820191_ruby-2.4.2/gemset.pristine-ruby-2.4.2@global.log
```

I'm… not quite sure what this means, or what I should do next. Any thoughts? I'm running macOS 10.12.6.

[Edit]: [Here's a copy](https://gist.github.com/gwijthoff/8a3e485537787604ac8d1bd4991ea889) of the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix as referenced in this [RVM GitHub issue](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3389) that involves installing zlib using brew and then re-installing ruby while pointing to that zlib directory.
As someone in that thread pointed out, this shouldn't be necessary. Still not sure why the problem arose.

Steps

```
$ brew install zlib
$ rvm remove 2.4.2
$ rvm install 2.4.2 —-with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11
```

Comment: I am sorry if a comment isn't the right way but I was not allowed to suggest edit. It looks some autoformat or similar thing happened to this block. the right option is with -- so
`rvm install 2.4.2 --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11`

Answer (score 0):

According to the RVM docs, you don't use ruby- in the command.
It should be:
    `$ rvm install 2.4.2`
I'm not sure if that matters or not though.
Have you tried upgrading RVM and Homebrew?

[Edit] Based on this info from the log file:

```
bigdecimal-1.3.0 +gemset_pristine:20> gem pristine --extensions bigdecimal --version 1.3.0
ERROR:  Loading command: pristine (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
+gemset_pristine:21> _failed+=( 'bigdecimal --version 1.3.0' )
```

Looks like a zlib problem.  Try installing (or re-installing) Command Line Tools.
`$ xcode-select --install`

There is a very similar issue on github https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4090
It was solved by running `$ brew doctor`

Comment: I get the same result running `$ rvm install 2.4.2` so it doesn't matter. Also, running latest versions of RVM [1.29.3] and Homebrew [1.3.5]

Comment: I can't test since I'm still on 10.11.6   Have you looked at the log file referenced in the error?

Comment: I did, but the error log didn't seem to contain any useful information that the terminal output didn't. But I might as well be looking at hieroglyphics. Here it is: https://gist.github.com/gwijthoff/8a3e485537787604ac8d1bd4991ea889

Comment: I edited my answer.  Looks like a zlib problem. (or possibly SSL related)

Comment: Very strange. Reinstalled command line tools and zlib.h is where it's supposed to be in `/usr/include/`. Maybe it's an issue with where RVM expects zlib to be? The problem seems to be confined to that one gem command, `pristine`. I think I'll post this as an issue on the RVM github. Thanks for your help, this is super frustrating.

Comment: If you get an answer, please post it here.  I'm really curious.  Somehow I don't think it's an RVM problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156687/discussion-between-david-watson-and-strobodyne).

Comment: I have just run the same `rvm reinstall 2.x.y` __twice__ :-) First, it failed with the error message above, then it succeeded...

Answer (score 0):

Just came up against this after needing to use SASS after a while. During which time I had upgraded to El Capitan. So Ruby was 'Old'.

**You could probably cut a lot of my steps out by running the following (with a little prior knowledge of the latest Ruby Version).**

`xcode-select --install
brew install zlib
rvm reinstall ruby-<latest_version> --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/<latest_version>`

---

This was how I had to go about it. I didn't need to uninstall in the end but I took a lot of wrong turns.

Initially I had to run this line to get xcode up to date:

`xcode-select --install`

Then install `zlib`

`brew install zlib`

Take a note of the directory zlib is installed in

`/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11`

Next update `rvm`

\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

Following these steps got me to the point where I was running the latest version of ruby `2.4.1`. But zlib wasn't linked to ruby.

So the final step was to run a reinstall

`rvm reinstall ruby-2.4.1 --with-zlib-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/zlib/1.2.11`